# emulator64-arm quit unexpectedly intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I get the popup

`emulator64-arm quit unexpectedly` when I try to run the emulator. I looked up a quick fix and the most popular one seems to be located here

http://timvoet.com/2013/01/04/avd-emulator-crashes-on-mac/

However, I dont have a `.avd` directory.

`~/.android/avd/.avd/emulator-user.ini`

Inside my avd. directory only contains

`.     ..     MyAvd0.avd    MyAvd0.ini`

I tried adding window.x=0 into MyAvd0.ini but that did not fix the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to do it for each AVD instance. Navigate into the .avd directory:

```
cd MyAvd0.avd
```

and you'll see `emulator-user.ini` in there. Open it up and set `window.x` and `window.y` to `0`, and then lock that file so it won't be overwritten again.

Comment: How do I lock the file? it is being overwritten unfortunately =[