# emulator64-x86 quit unexpectedly(in Android Studio on Mac(Yosemite))

Tags: android, macos, android-layout, android-studio

My question is very closely related to this one 
[emulator64-arm quit unexpectedly intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897009/emulator64-arm-quit-unexpectedly-intellij)

but inside my `Device.avd` file, I don't have emulator-user.ini. I searched the directory throughly but still I cant seem to find the file...

**My directory contains:**

1. config.ini
2. hardware-qemu.ini
3. hardware-qemu.ini.lock
4. sdcard.img
5. userdata.img

Comment: FInally, I figured out the answer myself, Recently I upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite and it kinda screwed up my permissions(to manipulate Virtual Memory, maybe). So, I opened my disk utility and repaired my permissions for Macintosh HD. And it worked!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I got the same issue. I repair my permission on my hd. but still was not able to have the missing emulator-user.ini